# SKTileMapNode animation not working well in real devices

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

I used multiple textures in SKTileDefinition to produce animations in SKTileMapNode. Its fine in simulator, however, it looks shaky in real devices. How can I fix it?

iOS version: 11.1

testing devices: iPhone 7plus, iPad Pro 10.5, iPad Air 2

[image] the tile map animation is fine in simulator.

[image] the same animation look shaky in real devices.

Comment: I am going to guess you are not properly handling 1x 2x 3x graphics

Comment: I use only 1x resolution. Both animation above are built with exactly the same code and graphics. The only different is that the upper one is running in simulator, while the lower one running in real device.